# How to extract statistics/data from an iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-application

I am building an iOS app similar to a gameplay, after some time of gameplay, there are certain dataset that is produced like: for how much time a user played, which time of day the person played, etc. After the app is installed on an iPhone, How do I get theses statistics out of the app to do research/data analysis. The app installed would from my personal developer account, not through App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can write that data to CSV and then then you can export that data using UIDocumentInteractionController.